# Toast when no item is selected in listView

Tags: android, listview, if-statement, kotlin

Hi guys I´m trying to make this work:

```
         button.setOnClickListener {
            if (list1.choiceMode == android.widget.ListView.CHOICE_MODE_NONE){
                toast("You need to choose an item first")
            }
            else {
                val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                builder.setTitle("Alert")
                builder.setMessage("This service requires data?")
                builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", { dialogInterface: DialogInterface, i: Int ->
                    ListView.visibility = View.GONE
                    website.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                })
                builder.setNegativeButton("No", { dialogInterface: DialogInterface, i: Int -> })
                builder.show()
            }

        }
```

I´m trying to display a message when the user press the button but he hasn´t selected any item from the list1. And if everything is ok, I want it to get the listView visibility set to gone and  the website visibility set to visible.

All i get when pressing the button is the toast message.

EDITED:

```
    val nameofanimals = arrayOf("cat","dog","parrot")

internal lateinit var adapteranimals: ArrayAdapter<String>
```

here is my list:

```
val list1 = findViewById(R.id.list1) as ListView


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:visibility="gone">


    </ListView>
```

my adapter:

```
adapteranimals = ArrayAdapter(
        this@MainActivity,
        R.layout.list1layout,
        nameofanimals)
list1.adapter = adapteranimals
```

Now I need to display a toast message when none of cat, dog or parrot is selected, and want to set the visibility of a webviewer and a listview layout to visible and to gone when the user actually select one of the options in my list

Answer (score 0):

In order to make your items selectable in a list there are two key methods that you need to call on the listview.

Before `button.setOnClickListener` add these two lines

```
        list1.setItemsCanFocus(false);
        list1.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
```

Then inside your `onClickListener` do this:

```
Object selectedObj = list1.getSelectedItem(); 

if (selectedObj == null) {
 showToast();
} else {
 doSomethingElse();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, all that i need is to display a toast message when a user press a button without having selected an item from the list. and if they have then perform an action. I´m trying to perform a conditional action here.

Comment: @GaboWalker are you using a ListView?

Comment: Try using the code I suggested and see if it works for you.

Comment: same thing happens, it only displays the toast message no matters what. ty anyways for your help